# how to use output of bashful splice to assign it to a Latex counter?

Tags: bashful

This is very frustrating. I can obtain my Linux group ID and assign it to a Latex counter.

When using the `\bash..\END` construct it works, but when using `splice` construct it does not work. I'll show MWE to explain more.

This works. I get the group ID from bash and set it to a Latex counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}
\newcounter{c}
\begin{document}
\bash
id -g
\END
\setcounter{c}{\bashStdout}

my group ID is \arabic{c}
\end{document}
```

compile `pdflatex -shell-esc foo.tex` and the PDF file shows

```
      my group ID is 1000
```

This does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}
\newcounter{c}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{c}{\splice{id -g}}
my group ID is \arabic{c}
\end{document}
```

The compile error is

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\immediate 
l.8 \setcounter{c}{\splice{id -g}}                                    
?
```

It looks like the counter is being set *before* bash is run and returned the 1000 value. So I need to tell it to expand before? I do not understand the expand commands, but I tried

```
  \expandafter\setcounter{c}{\splice{id -g}}
```

and

```
  \setcounter{c}{\expandafter\splice{id -g}}
```

but nothing is working.  It is clearly an evaluation order issue. Is there a way to make `splice` work in the above? I'd like to learn why it is not working.

Package reference is [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bashful)

This is what the documentaion says about `splice`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The value argument of `\setcounter` has to _expand_ to a number, not be some arbitrary non expandable code that eventually would typeset a number, `\setcounter{c}{\def\foo{3}\foo}` doesn't work either.

Comment: why make it so complicated your value for your group id presumably doesn't change so why require shell escape to look it up every time?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that was just an example. I am using the bash command to obtain different information. But using `id -g` for illustrations.

Comment: OK but It's unlikely to work inside `\setcounter` I would guess.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, thanks. I am switching to egrep `\shellcommand` which works! but it has problem when I use `breqn` package, which I must use. I posted separate question on that. Latex is so hard.

Comment: @Nasser No, it isn't hard. It may be difficult to get things it has not been thought for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The working of `\splice` is easy to explain:

```
% bashful.sty, line 232:
\newcommand\splice[1]{%
  \bashIV{#1}%
  \expandFileName@BL{\BL@stdoutFile}%
  \CatchFileDef{\BL@file@contents}{\BL@stdoutFile}{\relax}%
  \ignorespaces\BL@file@contents\unskip
}
```

The first thing it does is `\bashIV`:

```
% bashful.sty, line 211:
\newcommand\bashIV[1]{%
  \logBL{BashIV: begin}%
  \makeDirectory@BL
  \generateScriptFile@BL{#1}\relax
  \executeScriptFile@BL
  \logBL{BashIV: done}%
}%
```

The command writes out a script that's executed as we see from the definition of `\executeScriptFile@BL`:

```
% bashful.sty, line 299:
\newcommand\executeScriptFile@BL{%
  \edef\command@BL{\BL@shell \space \BL@scriptFile}%
  \if@hide@BL@
    \logBL{Adding a "cd command"}%
    \edef\command@BL{cd \directory@BL;\command@BL}
  \fi%
  \edef\command@BL{\command@BL \space >\BL@stdoutFile \space 2>\BL@stderrFile}%
  \edef\command@BL{\command@BL \space || echo $? >\BL@exitCodeFile}%
  \edef\command@BL{\BL@shell\space -c "\command@BL"}%
  \logBL{Executing:^^J \command@BL}%
  \immediate\write18{\command@BL}%
}%
```

The standard output is redirected to `\BL@stdoutFile` (which stands for a uniquely named file with extension `.stdout`.

Such a file is read in with `\CatchFileDef` and its contents is stored in `\BL@file@contents` for *printing* it, as testified by `\ignorespaces` and `\unskip`.

There's no real way to make this work in the argument to `\setcounter` that should be something that expands to a number, not to the instructions for printing a number.

You could define a different command:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\splicesave}[2]{%
  \bashIV{#1}%
  \expandFileName@BL{\BL@stdoutFile}%
  \CatchFileDef{#2}{\BL@stdoutFile}{}% \relax was redundant
}
\makeatother
```

and do

```
\splicesave{id -g}{\foo}
\setcounter{c}{\foo}
```

Comment: I wish `splicesave` is available in original package.